# "Turn on" rsubmit as if it were an option

Tags: sas, server

I run PC SAS and most of the time I'm sending blocks of code to the server, like

```
rsubmit;
[code]
endrsubmit;
```

I'm tired of typing `rsubmit` and `endrsubmit` so much.  I wish it were possible to turn on `rsubmit` as an option, something like

```
options rsubmit = all;
```

and then I can run bits and pieces of code while I'm programming without all that extra typing.  Does an option like this exist?

Comment: If your highlighting code to submit you can probably add a hot key to rsubmit the code instead of local submit. I think F3 is local. I know you can right click and rsubmit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your key settings (type 'keys' into the Command Box), set CTRL-F3 to `rsubmit wait=yes`.

You can then press F3 to locally submit code, and CTRL-F3 to remote submit code.

Comment: Clarification: I was not sure what the "Command Box" is.  I found something like a command box right in the upper left corner of my SAS interface, just under the File menu.  It worked.

Comment: If your `keys` settings are not saved for some reason, you can also set it programatically, e.g. in your autoexec, `dm "keydef CTRL-F3 'rsubmit wait=yes'"`

Comment: Clarification II:  You don't have to go looking for the "Command Box."  Just hit F9 and this should bring up the key settings window.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but you could cut out most of the typing by defining an abbreviation under Tools > Add Abbreviation...

I have mine set up as follows:

rs:

```
rsubmit;
endrsubmit;
```

sr:

```
endrsubmit;
rsubmit;
```

Answer (score 1):

`RSUBMIT` is submitting code to a server.  One way to do this would be to turn over your code to the server, and execute it directly from there.  This is available in some instances and not others (depending on your setup), but many times it's possible.  You can do your development locally, and then use Git or SVN to promote code to the server and execute it there when you want to use the full database or whatever particular reason you are RSUBMITting.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a button to your toolbar that can rsubmit your code and you can also bind a hotkey (like the f8 that submits code) to run your rsubmit. You will need to setup the environment for rsubmit just as you would normally or via an autoexec.sas program. Here is a link to a document that talks about other options you can customize your toolbar to use.

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi28/240-28.pdf

1. Menu bar : tools | customize
2. select the icon you would like to place yours next too
3. click the icon second row on the left (little blue star upper left corner of the button) to add new
   command = rsubmit
4. help text and tip text with whatever makes sense for you.